# JSF Primefaces: Gmap component into an autocompleter

Tags: java, jsf, autocomplete, primefaces

my requirements is to put an gmap in the autocompleter component (instead of use a image I want to show a gmap).

Is it possible?

This is basic gmap i want to use:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapBasic.jsf

this is the gmap code:

> ```
>   <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" tyle="width:600px;height:400px" />
> ```

This is the autocompleter component with an image:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteItemtip.jsf 
(Type "X" to see the image)

can anyone help me please?

Comment: It should be possible. Which attribute do you want to use in the autocomplete field?

Comment: Autocompleter will be a pojo list. This pojo includes a map location, I want to show the map with that location instead an image...
Example: http://www.sixt.com/

Comment: Just try it. The example in the showcase shows a `<p:graphicImage`/>, why don't try with a map? You have the locations stored in the pojos, so be sure to pass them through params to the  `<p:gmap/>` object.

Comment: That doesnt work, it shows a no-navagable map :(. Only a static image of a map

Comment: Have you tried that map outside the autocomplete with fixed values, as you have in your question? I suppose it's working like that. Can you post the code which you already have?

Comment: Hi, sorry my code is no longer exist, im trying to make a new componen to do this, instead to use the autocompleter. I tried to put the <p:gmap/> with static values at first, without dinamic data. Thank you very much for your responses